# retaining a list of all local push notifications in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, apple-push-notifications

As part of an app I'm writing, it keeps a list of reminders and uses local notifications to display them at the required time.

What I would like to determine is a list of these notifications so that I don't have to recreate the list upon each edit or new notification.

Is there any documentation or examples/tutorials that demonstrate this behaviour?

Thanks,
Matt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He is talking about `local notifications`, not `push notifications`. You can use 
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` to get the complete list of scheduled notifications.

Comment: That's surprisingly simple to implement. Thanks heaps for your response.

Answer (score 1):

No, and I’m afraid it’s not a good choice.  Push notifications are not meant to be used as true data, and it can expire, get overwritten by newer notifications, etc.  Notifications can have iOS launch your app, but that’s it and that’s not going to happen 100% (the user might just dismiss the notification).

Comment: im working on something similar and think you may be able to guide me better! If a user does not click the notification banner on opening the application the next time I would like to know if the notification has happened. I guess I am asking is a notification alert available to an application if it is not opened using the banner. If my query to you is not clear let me know and I will open a new question and present it better TY  - james